# Is stockx.com blocking webscraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web scrape from "https://stockx.com/" using bs4 but I get:

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.

Is there any way I can fix this?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://stockx.com/"

uClient = uReq(my_url)
```

Comment: Probably: https://medium.com/@zaly2803/using-the-unofficial-stockx-api-1775628c4605

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not programming related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing a `useragent` header seems to solve the issue.

Try something like this:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq, Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://stockx.com/"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.3"}

uClient = uReq(Request(url=my_url, headers=headers))
```

But do know that if the data you're trying to **scrape** is dynamic, `bs4` wouldn't be of much help. consider using `pyppeteer` or `selenium`, etc.. for that.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use scrapy, it'll try to request the site again and it'll follow redirects.